# Most anonymous way to crawl a search engine

Tags: ruby, search-engine, anonymous

I'm writing a script in Ruby that searches search engines using a whole bunch of search queries. I want this script to remain anonymous when used by a user. So far the script will change user agents and use a random header. Is there a certain way or a certain search engine that I should be using to remain anonymous?

I've seen DuckDuckGo is a good start, it also has an API, due to which it is apparently not logging data and using Tor, but what if I wanted to use more than one search engine? For example, using multiple threads to crawl multiple search engines, and stay anonymous on all engines.

How can I accomplish this?

I know about Rubys proxy features, I'm just not entirely sure how to use them is another problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be anonymous on Internet, one of the best choice is tor. You can use it by yourself and access to any website

First you have to connect to the tor network

```
tor --SOCKSPort 9050
```

Then you can use this gem: https://github.com/astro/socksify-ruby

And access any website anonymously:

```
require 'socksify/http'
require 'net/http'
Net::HTTP.SOCKSProxy('127.0.0.1', 9050).start('some.website.com', 80) do |http|
  http.get('/')
end
```

Please read tor documentation if you need to be anonymous for security reasons, it is complete and important if you want to use it correctly.

The target website can easily know the traffic is comming from tor network (but it won't known where the traffic come from), be reasonable while crawling, you don't want webmaster to block tor...

Comment: I'm confused about the `tor --SOCKS` part, what does that do? Sorry I know very little about proxies and how they work

Comment: It tells to listen on port 9050. Then you connect to this port with Net::HTTP.SOCKSProxy. Your Http requests will be issued through the proxy

Comment: So basically Tor is my local IP connected through port 9050?

Answer (score 1):

Tor is a good option if you want some requests per day but most search engines have Tor outgoing IP's blacklisted so I think you would not enjoy a good ride. If you can pay some money for a service that can keep your crawling activity anonymous and avoid you the hassle of dealing with proxies, then I would recommend to use ProxyCrawl API [Anonymous Crawler Proxy](https://proxycrawl.com).

The API is easy to use and is free to try and support millions of sites, the price is pay as you go.